# MySQL - Get records from one table based on count of another table's column

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter, activerecord

I have a table called `students` and a table called `documents`. Each student can have any amount of document entries in the `documents` table, but might also have no document entries. Some of the documents might've been approved, others not.

table 1: `students`, table 2 `documents`. `student` PK is `user_id` and `document` PK is `document_id`, and `document` table has `user_id` in it as well. `document` table has column `approved` which can contain either a Yes or a No. So these two tables are linked by `user_id`

How can I write a MySQL query (or even better, in Active Record style for Code Igniter) that can list all students that have at least 1 unapproved document?

Comment: make an effort and we will help, dont and we wont.

Comment: I have been sitting with this now for an hour already. I have nothing concrete to show you. I tried variations of joins and inner queries with having clause, and none were successful. Just because I did not post my effort here does not mean I did not do any effort.

Comment: how do we know if a document has been approved? Do you have a boolean field?

Comment: You're looking for a `JOIN`. As for specifics, since your question doesn't give any we can only guess. A good question will have an example schema. To get that use `SHOW CREATE TABLE` and edit your question.

Comment: There is an enum column called "approved" that will have values "Yes" or "No"

Comment: You need to do a "join", which will include the "count" function, and will have a "where" clause. If you can provide the names of the columns and the relationship between the two tables, I can easily help you with the specifics of the sql query.

Comment: table 1: `students`, table 2 `documents`. `student` PK is `user_id` and `document` PK is `document_id`, and `document` table has `user_id` in it as well. `document` table has column `approved` which can contain either a Yes or a No. So these two tables are linked by `user_id`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
mysql> create table students (student_number int, student_first_name char(25), student_Last_name char(25));
```

Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.34 sec)

```
mysql> create table documents (student_number int, document_name char(25), approved bool);
```

Query OK, 0 rows affected (0.32 sec)

```
mysql> insert into students values (1,"F1","L1"),(2,"F2","L2"),(3,"F3","L3");
```

Query OK, 3 rows affected (0.19 sec)
Records: 3  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

```
mysql> insert into documents values (1,"D1",0),(1,"D2",1),(3,"D3",1);
```

Query OK, 3 rows affected (0.16 sec)
Records: 3  Duplicates: 0  Warnings: 0

```
mysql> select * from students where student_number in (select student_number from documents where !approved);
```

+----------------+--------------------+-------------------+
| student_number | student_first_name | student_Last_name |
+----------------+--------------------+-------------------+
|              1 | F1                 | L1                |
+----------------+--------------------+-------------------+
1 row in set (0.02 sec)

Comment: Thank you. I needed to join a few more tables and also add a group by (as my question was simplified to the part that I was struggling with), but your answer has gotten me on the right track.

Comment: @kobus - I'm glad you find it helpful.

Answer (score 0):

```
select distinct students.name from students join documents on 
students.user_id=documents.user_id where documents.user_id is No
```